# Cannot upgrade in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade

This is what I get when trying to upgrade the newly installed Ubuntu 20.04. I did try "apt autoremove", "apt clean", removing old and creating new symlinks and "--fix-broken install" but to no avail.

Any solutions?

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.6.7-1~18.04) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.6.7-1~18.04) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-kiwisolver : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
 python3-renderpm : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you added packages meant for an earlier Ubuntu version, namely Ubuntu 18.04. That introduced conflicts with the packages from Ubuntu 20.04.

Specifically, you have installed a version of the package `python3` which depends on other packages, namely `python3-minimal` in version `3.6.7-1~18.04` and `libpython3-stdlib` in version `3.6.7-1~18.04` (note the `18.04` in the names). But you already have installed newer version of those packages, being `3.8.2-0ubuntu2` (which is the correct version for Ubuntu 20.04). `apt` doesn't just downgrade stuff as a policy, so you've painted yourself a bit in the corner here ;) There are similar problems with `python3-kiwisolver` and `python3-renderpm`.

You may want to remove all packages meant for other versions of Ubuntu. If you specifically need Python 3.6 and/or any software that depends on this version of Python, I defer to the Python experts around here for ways to solve that. But trying it this way basically asks for trouble ;)

Comment: Thank you. I cannot even remove any other packages since I get the same message. Any way to remove some of these packages other than apt remove or autoremove?